# Windows 2019 and IIS Virtual SMTP Virtual Relay (Office 365)

Tags: iis, smtp, office365

I have hit a wall with this setup and I cant for the life of me figure this out, despite having setup a few other Virtual SMTP servers in the past. Maybe something has changed in 2019?

I will provide as much info as possible to help you help me :)

I have installed SMTP Server and Telnet Client on my 2019 server, I have followed guides and rechecked my settings to ensure all is setup correctly.

[General]

- I have all unassigned IP addresses allowed

[Access]

- Authentication set to 'Anonymous'
- TLS Greyed out
- Connection control and relay restrictions set to allow all with a blank list below.

[Messages]

- All left as default

[Delivery]

> Outbound Security

- Basic Authentication with the Office 365 username and password set.

> Outbound connection

- TCP Port: 587

> Advanced Delivery

- Smart host is set to: smtp.office365.com

[LDAP] and [Security] tabs are default.

The Office 365 user is set to *SMTP auth enabled* and I have confirmed this via PowerShell.

`telnet 127.0.0.1 25` shows:

`220 mydomain.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service, Version: 10.0.17763.1697 ready at  Tue, 7 Sep 2021 13:53:35 +1000`

However, when trying to send an email via this relay it stays in the C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue directory and I get the below in the event log:

`Message delivery to the host 'X.X.X.X' failed while delivering to the remote domain 'recipientsdomain.com' for the following reason: The remote SMTP service rejected AUTH negotiation.`

I will probably kick myself once I figure this out, but I must be going mad.

*EDIT*: forgot to add...

I can also telnet from the network to `smtp.office365.com` on port 587 and have also configured a connector in Office 365 for WAN IPs which are in use on my network.

Thanks!
Bil

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after a few more hours of troubleshooting. I saw some failed sign in requests in the admin center, which lead me down the conditional access path.

I had some previously setup location blocking in Office 365, so disabled that as a precaution but I think what ended up doing it was disabling security defaults in azure.

ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults

Comment: in case its solved, please accept your own answer